# Multipath between two laptops

Tags: networking, rsync

I have two laptops, let's call them primary and secondary. I work on primary and would like the secondary to have the same data available. Secondary has very limited port selection (at 7" that's not a surprise) most importantly, it doesn't have Thunderbolt so I can't just link the two laptops together at 10gbps. There are (finally) 802.3bz USB adapters at both 2.5gbps and 5gbps speeds but for the price of a single 2.5gbps USB adapter one can buy a 4x1gbps USB adapter (or for half of that get a three port USB 3.0 hub w/Ethernet + three more Ethernet adapters). I am wondering if I got two, would it be possible to connect two laptops together, would it be possible to get 4gbps out of that for file sync purposes? Perhaps with MPTCP or does rsync support such natively?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do to connect them via an ethernet network cable. Then you can simply rsync over the IP addresses they associate via you connecting "direct" using the network manager. I did it early today using gnome on Debian 10.